# d3.js re-sizable Line Graph with percentage

Tags: d3.js

I trying to make this line chart resizable with percentage instead with pixels.

Can any one please help me to find the solution?

Here's [a link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)

Comment: can you elaborate on _resizable_? What exaactly do you want to resize? What Have you tried?

Comment: I mean when you change browser size (width for example) I want my graph's width will change too, but not using fixed size(pixels) but using relative size(percentage).

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can help you?

Comment: I don't think that this is very easy. Note that at most, you can resize the _container_ SVG immediately when the browser window resizes. As for the _contents_ of the SVG - what actually is created with d3.js - they don't relate to the SVG container's dimensions whatsoever... This means that you would have to write your script in a way that builds the visualization relative to the containers dimensions to begin with, and that is a tricky job, IMO.

Comment: the code that I using is in the link: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Answer (score 1):

D3 selectors [can accept a *node reference*](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select) as well as a string selector - utilize that to your benefit. Put the SVG in a container, which can have any unit type for its dimensions (relative or absolute), and set the SVG size by the containers'.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('canvas');
var svg = d3.select(el).append('svg');
setSize(svg, el);

function setSize(child, parent) {
    child && parent && 
    child.attr('width', parent.clientWidth)
         .attr('height', parent.clientHeight);
}
```

Attach a `resize` event to the window, and update the SVG size on callbacks:

```js
var that = this;
window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
    that.setSize(el);
});
```

This is oversimplified, of course, and had not been tested, but it should get you started.

See the [docs on the `resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/resize) on Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: But this will set only size of SVG container, But what about the  all content of SVG? For example the variables of "path elements" they will be still absolute

Comment: i said *it should get you started*... if you build the line chart as a scalable chart, this solution would allow you to stretch it to fit its container. what you're asking is out of scope. SO is not meant to provide full solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When using D3, if you want to scale the x or y axis, it is doable and easy, if can adjust to your data range . You can just reset the scale of the axis.

Take this as an example to develop:
http://mpf.vis.ywng.cloudbees.net/

(click the legend to add curves, when new curves comes in...the y axis scale is adjusted...for your problem, I think can be solved by just modify the code a little bit)